# Can't edit value of WYSIWYG Editor after first save

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, wysiwyg

I have added a WYSIWYG Editor to the dropdown field in the individual options of a configurable product.

But there is a bug. If I first create a new option of type dropdown and add a new row and fill in the values and click on "save" then the page is getting reloaded and all values are successfully saved as expected.

[image]

But If I now try to edit the value in the WYSIWYG Form (WYS 1) and click on save. Then the same value is still there.

All other attributes are changing as expected on save, even the attribute "action" which I created on my own.

Why is the WYSIWYG Editor not saving?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was that I called the tinyMCE init function even though it was already initialized on a hidden place which I only figured out after inspecting the source code of the site.

After removing the redundant call it works!